# Создание подключения к удалённому рабочему столу через RDP

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, rdp

Как сейчас в VS 2017 или 2019 создать подключение на C# к удалённому рабочему столу через RDP с возможностью трансляции этого рабочего стола?

Comment: А причем здесь студия? RDP делается силами винды. Или вы имели в виду Live Share?

Comment: @Bulson Нет, при помощи Windows Forms и RDP Client'а можно создать свое приложение по удаленному доступу, и я попробовал ввести код из интернета, но ничего не получилось, и я не могу понять ошибку.

Comment: Тогда добавьте свой код в вопрос.